# How do I add a search function to gnome classic (fallback) panel?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-classic, appmenu, search

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise with the GNOME desktop environment. I like using the GNOME Fallback ("Classic") better than the default GNOME (i.e., better than GNOME Shell). The only thing that I miss in GNOME Fallback is the search function in the panel.

In GNOME, when you press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (<kbd>Windows</kbd> key), you can immediately start typing the name of the application and then click on the desired application from the results shown to launch that app. I find that in "classic" GNOME, it is fully menu driven; there is no option to search for installed applications using the panel or from within the Applications menu.

I was wondering if this feature could be added to GNOME Fallback, so that instead of going by the menu, I can for example press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and then type the name of the application and then launch it from the results shown.

I have only very limited exposure, am still figuring things out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I somehow managed to add the *Search for Files* option to my Places menu. I'm not sure exactly which step I took to make this work, but I'll tell you exactly what I did:

- Install *Main Menu* via the Software Centre.
- Install *GNOME Desktop Utilities* via the Software Centre.
- Open your Home Folder and click: *Bookmarks* -> *Add Bookmark*. This will add a Bookmark to your 'Home Folder'.
- Click 'Edit Bookmarks...' and click on the new 'Home Folder' bookmark.
- Type "Search" as the name, and set the location to `gnome-search-tool`, instead of `/home/user/`.

Now after following those steps I suddenly find a *Search For Files...* option in my Places menu. I haven't restarted the computer yet so I don't know if it will remain after a boot, but if it does then we are in business!

Also, I did install the MATE desktop in Ubuntu, but since this is Gnome Classic "No Effects" that I am running, I doubt MATE would have any effect.

Edit: The *Search for Files...* option is still there after a reboot!

Edit: The following link will take you to my post on this topic at the Ubuntu Forums, where I have attached an image showing that I now have the *Search for Files* option:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12161664#post12161664

Comment: Yep, if you install gnome-search-tool and then add a bookmark with the location as "gnome-search-tool", it will automagically add it as the "Search for files" option available by default in previous versions of Ubuntu. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Synapse for this.

https://launchpad.net/synapse-project

It can search files, programs and lot more. You can bring it up with your own shortcut keys