# Is there a synapse like search bar as a desktop widget for Gnome desktop fallback mode?

Tags: gnome-classic, conky, synapse

I want to add a fixed desktop widget to my gnome fallback desktop.

The widget should simply have a search bar and below it, options to search where.

I don't want to hit any key for it to start.

It should be like a conky layer.

The functionality should be kinda like synapse. But no logo and all.

And it should be transparent to seamlessly merge with my desktop background.

I searched on this forum and on internet but only found this - [How do I add a search function to gnome classic (fallback) panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168442/how-do-i-add-a-search-function-to-gnome-classic-fallback-panel).

The above question does not help me in anyway.

Is there any way I can achieve this, preferably using conky.

Any other method will also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Indicator-Synapse is a new attempt at presenting results from the powerful application/file launcher Synapse.

To install in Ubuntu **12.04**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/unstable-upstream

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:birdie-team/stable

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse libkeybinder-3.0-0
```

For other releases please check:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/spotlight-like-tool-coming-to-pear-os-other-distros

[image]

Comment: I know about that. It doesn't seems to work in Gnome Classic with no effects mode. And I don't use unity.